# How to read from openTSDB with a JSON POST?

Tags: json, http, post, request, opentsdb

I am running my openTSDB on a virtual maschine and want to read data with a JSON POST request from a client.

Baseurl is the URL to my VM.

Whenever i send this request, i get an error  "Unable to pass the given JSON" in my openTSDB. So what's wrong with my request?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The Json-Request is supposed to represent this GET Request (which works):

baseurl+"/api/query?start=1356994800000&m=sum:Leistung";

```
        String url = baseurl;
        URL obj = new URL(url + "/api/query");


        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");



        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeChars("{\n" +
                "    \"start\": 1356994800000,\n" +
                "    \"queries\": [\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "            \"aggregator\": \"sum\",\n" +
                "            \"metric\": \"Leistung\"\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "    ]\n" +
                "}");
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();


        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        con.disconnect();
        in.close();
        System.out.println(response.toString());
```